# Simple assignment notation question

Tags: notation

this is an elementary question, but I haven't encountered this notation before:

[image: Interval notation]

S, and T are being assigned but what does "/" signify here?

Thanks

Comment: [Quotient group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These both signify a quotient of $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to certain [group actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbits_and_stabilizers). The group $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ acts on $\mathbb{R}$ via $(n,x) \mapsto n+x$. The orbit $\mathcal{O}_x$ of a point $x$ is the set $\{x+n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and the quotient $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is the set $\{\mathcal{O}_x \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$. The orbit of any integer is just $\mathbb{Z}$ and each noninteger is in the orbit of exactly one point in the unit interval $(0,1)$, so if we identify points which are in the same orbit, we get the unit interval with the endpoints identified.